# Making Wave Texture Material Like Cardboard Flute

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, shaders, procedural

I'm still a newbie and I need a texture, not a mesh or wavy object,

Maybe using wave texture, I hope the result is like picture below,

[image: like cardboard flute]

I'm using 2.9

[image]

Below, is my blender screen capture, it's still straight, I dont have idea to make those texture applied to my mesh

[image: it's still straigth, I dont have idea to make those texture applied to my mesh]

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger yes, I need some tutorial or the node (material node) so I can have those texture to my objects, I've just edited/ add my blender screen capture

Comment: @Damar .. it's a bit trickier than it looks to get an even thickness in the wave-stroke :).

Comment: @RobinBetts ... So, do you know how to get the trick??? :)

Comment: One way:  overlap 2 grids, with alternating half-circles.. a sine-wave  won't do it easily, if you want even thickness. Will get to it, if someone doesn't get there first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be this setting:

[image]

Using:

[image]

We have four input parameters:

Scale: to control the scale of the pattern

Length: the wave length

Interval: threshold between each line

Height: the height of the wave

Then,

From X (scaled by scale * length), the sine.

From Y (scaled, reduced to the interval, recentered around 0 and multiplied by the height) the value to compare to the sine.

[image]

Comment: Hrrmph... good enough, I suppose.. ;)

Comment: Should be better if more rounded probably, @RobinBetts.

Comment: It's the thickness of the stroke that can't be perfect with a sine wave, because there is no analytic  shortest-distance-to-sine function. If you use Y-distance, as you have, the waves are thicker at the peaks. So, I'll pop one in, using circles instead, when I have a mo, but I'm sure that's way OTT.

Comment: @lemon I really appreciate it, this one is material that I need, really helpfull, thank very much to you